# Size of parent and child class with same members

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, sizeof

I'm writing some network code in C++11, and I have a doubt about the size of some packets.

Is the size of the following two structures guaranteed by the standard to be the same? even without **attribute**((packed));  (that I know it's non standard).

```
struct A
{
uint16_t a;
} __attribute__((packed));

template<class T>
struct B : A
{
T getA() { return static_cast<T>(a);}
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you wonder? What is the *real* problem you need to solve?

Comment: you can `static_assert` that the sizes are the same so the compiler will yell if it doesn't meet your expectations

Comment: [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407290/memory-layout-differences-in-structs) imply there is some guarantee, though `packed` may weaken or strengthen that

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude two things: (1) I just want to know this for personal knowledge (2) the real problem is to write this code in a library and use other types (enums for instance) in the client code instead of uint16_t in this case.

Comment: @kmdreko yes, that was something I wanted to do, but I preferred to be sure anyway