# Calling an unmanaged function which return object by value

Tags: c#, .net-core, coreclr

Assume the following:

Let us have a C++ class:

```cpp
class ExampleClass
{
 private:
    int var1;
 public:
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Assume also following C++ function which we want to call from .NET Core app with PInvoke or using EmitCalli:

```cpp
extern "C" ExampleClass CreateObject()
```

So C++ function returns instance of ExampleClass by value. Is there any way to get this instance on managed part as byte array (assuming that size of ExampleClass is known).

As I remember, in most native x86(x64) calling conventions C++ functions which return structures actully have pointer to the structure to fill as one of the parameters. Will this hint work with NET Core: allocate byte array on managed part and pass pointer as first parameter to unmanaged call?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK you can't use C++ classes from .NET code. If you want to use an instance of that class from C#, one option might be to build a C++/CLI wrapper library that contains a class with the same API as `ExampleClass` and internally calls the C++ function. I'm not sure if C++/CLI works with .NET Core though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in C++

```cpp
ExampleClass CreateClass();
```

will return a block of bytes of `sizeof(ExampleClass)` and in absence of virtual members and inheritance it will be plain object and equivalent to same struct definition (see more about this here: [Structure of a C++ Object in Memory Vs a Struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422830/structure-of-a-c-object-in-memory-vs-a-struct) )

P/Invoke marshaller should be able to deal with this without a problem.

It it not an IntPtr, it's an actual memory block for C and C++.
IntPtr equivalent would be

```cpp
ExampleClass * CreateClass();
```

I am not sure why it returns the instance instead of a pointer but they probably had their reasons.

so if you define it

```
public struct ExampleClass
{
    public int Var1;
}
```

you should be fine (except if class structure is more complex you would need to check what was layout in C++ compilation, specifically padding. For example class with 2 `bool`s may yield size of 16 in some padding).

see more here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute